# Laravel find stores within 10KM using lat and long values

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel project which has users and stores. user can add addresses with `lat` and

`long` so that while adding an address I want check that is there any store available within 10km .

stores table example values

```
id | name | lat | long|
1  |  a   |9.00 | 7.00|
1  |  a   |7.00 | 12.0|
```

and user input

```
{
  "lat":'some value',
   "long":"some value'
also some other parameters
}
```

I found that there is `Haversine distance calculation` method but I am pretty confused to how to implement it on laravel..

I know its not a good way to ask someone to write code for me but if anyone can then it will be helpful for me Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code in your model

```
public function ScopeDistance($query,$from_latitude,$from_longitude,$distance)
{
  // This will calculate the distance in km
  // if you want in miles use 3959 instead of 6371
  $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$from_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) ) AS distance');
  return $query->select('*')->addSelect($raw)->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )->groupBy('distance')->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
}
```

And you can use it with something like this

```
$ads = Ad::with(['user','photos'])->distance($from_latitude,$from_longitude,$distance)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my function that I used just recently to get nearest warehouses by distance in ASC order

```
public static function getNearestWarehouse($dropOffAddress)
{
    return self::select('id', 'name', 'lat', 'long', DB::raw(sprintf(
            '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(%1$.7f)) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`long`) - radians(%2$.7f)) + sin(radians(%1$.7f)) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS distance',
            $dropOffAddress->lat,
            $dropOffAddress->long
        )))
        ->having('distance', '<', 10)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
        ->get();
}
```

Just change the variables according to your needs and you are done